# Returning a value from an async call within a PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a non PCL method that grabs data from a RESTful service which is then deserialised and returns the data back. It looks like this

```
    public WeatherData GetWeather
    {
        get
        {
            if (!ftrackData.Online)
                return new WeatherData();

            string param = string.Format("lat={0}&lon={1}&APPID={2}", AppDelegate.Self.Latitude, AppDelegate.Self.Longitude, AppDelegate.Self.WeatherID);
            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?" + param) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            string responseContent;
            try
            {
                using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                var deserial = Deserialize<WeatherData>(responseContent);
                return deserial;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deserialiser failed : {0}--{1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

(the data is coming from openweathermap)

I've moved this over to my PCL and come up with the following

```
    public WeatherData GetWeather
    {
        get
        {
            var param = string.Format("lat={0}&lon={1}&APPID={2}", App.Self.Latitude, App.Self.Longitude, App.Self.WeatherID);
            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?" + param) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            var Weather = new WeatherData();
            string responseContent;
            try
            {
                var asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(s =>
                        {
                            var response = (s.AsyncState as WebRequest).EndGetResponse(s);

                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                            Weather = Deserialize<WeatherData>(responseContent);
                        }), request);
                return Weather;

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Deserialiser failed : {0}--{1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                return Weather;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code builds without an issue, but is not awaiting before returning the weather data.

I've tried adding `.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` to the end of the `BeginGetResponse` but the Weather object is still returned before the call completes.

The return can't be added into the anonymous callback as the callback returns void.

I've also tried adding

```
if (asyncResult.IsCompleted)
   return Weather;
```

but this will no compile as not all paths return a value.

How can get the return not to return until Weather has been filled from within the anonymous call back?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `WebRequest.GetResponseAsync`? Can you use .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: @Nodoid: It's generally considered a poor approach to do an *asynchronous network call* within a *property getter*. A better approach would be an asynchronous method.

Comment: It's simple - use a method. There's a lot of "code smell" coming out of the code you've shared - a property should be smaller in code size, and it shouldn't touch anything outside its own class, especially not network or db or anything else like that